# Ext JS 5 Programmatically click actioncolumn gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs, extjs5

I have a grid view that has rows, and within each rows have an action column that you can click. I want to programmatically click the action column and run whatever event it does. The action column's got a itemID as well. Here's what i got so far,

```
var yourgrid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid[itemId=yourgridname]')[0]; 
var record = yourgrid .getSelectionModel().select(0, true);
```

How do you get click the action column ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/events.html)

> Firing your own events is done by calling fireEvent with an event
>   name.

```
var actionColumn = Ext.getCmp('#actionColumnId');
actionColumn.fireEvent('click', actionColumn);
```

Comment: I've tried this and it returns true, but there are no event firing. var actioncolumn = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('actioncolumn[itemId=actioncolumnId]')[0]; actioncolumn.fireEvent('click', actioncolumn);